# trainset not running on jupyterlab

Tags: deep-learning

I am running a deep learning program on jupyterlab of anaconda.
I have a trainset of 28000 pairs of images from various sources
and a testset of 300 pairs of images

I ran the program successfully both on trainset and testset
and encountered a problematic division by zero bug
which I attempted to repair

after repair attempt, I ran the proram again
this time, only testset was executed. trainset wasn't
but testset now runs with many epochs
this wasn't so previously

Is anyone familiar with what's going on? because I haven't a clue
assistance would be greatly appreciated
if anyone is interested in offering it
thanks

fixed division by zero bug
unsure about success of remedy
program doesn't run trainset
only testset
and with epochs
something that didnt happen before